# Replacing a whole array in React Redux - calling a dispatch function without infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am relatively new to Redux.
I have the following action -

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const currentListSlice = createSlice({
  name: "currentList",
  initialState: [1, 2, 3],

  reducers: {
    setCurrentList: (state, action) => {
      return action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setCurrentList } = currentListSlice.actions;

export default currentListSlice.reducer;
```

The initialState:[1,2,3] is for development only - The initialState will be empty and will be updated with a function that will use data from firebase.

Next, I'm calling the array and rendering a card from each object, using the numbers in the state to get the rest of the info from the data objects.

```
const preList = useSelector((state) => state.currentList);
  const list = [];
  preList.map((item) => list.push(DATA[item]));
```

list is being used as the data in a Flatlist.
So far so good.

Then I am calling the function to update currentList on redux like this -

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setCurrentList(fiveRandomBeaches(DATA.length)));
  }, [preList]);
```

I am going into an infinite loop.

To test, I added a button and called the dispatch with onPress event and the function works just fine, so no issues with the function.

```
dispatch(setCurrentList(fiveRandomBeaches(DATA.length)))
```

How do I call the dispatch function here without getting the infinite loop?
Thanks

I really don't think the fiveRandomBeaches function is relevant to the issue but here goes

```
export const fiveRandomBeaches = (dataLength) => {
  let beachesList = [];
  let uniqueBeachesList;
  let rndBeach;

  do {
    rndMarker = Math.floor(Math.random() * dataLength);
    beachesList.push(rndMarker);
    uniqueBeachesList = [...new Set(beachesList)];
  } while (uniqueBeachesList.length < 5);
  return uniqueBeachesList;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maxbe just a point on the syntax, since your problem god solved by someone else:

```
const list = [];
preList.map((item) => list.push(DATA[item]));
```

map() function is already returning an array, you can just save time by making use of it. Therefore try this instead of the above code:

```
const list = preList.map((item) => DATA[item]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect` has a dependency on `preList` and that is causing the infinite loop. `setCurrentList` will update it and cause the effect to run again ad infinitum.
Removing `preList` from the dependency array should solve your problem.

Comment: Fredrick, your solution works, thanks. However, I got the infinite loop even when instead of using the fiveRandomBeaches, I just pushed manually a different array [5,6,7,8]. In that case, currentList didn't actually change so I do not understand the infinite loop there. How would you make sure that page does rerender, even if currentList is being update from a different component? Or will Redux take care of that ?